# Board game vocabulary

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

What are the typical translations in Spanish for the following terms related to board games?

- board game
- board
- (playing) pieces
- deck of cards
- to roll the dice
- to move forward
- to move backwards
- to jump
- squares/spaces (individual locations on the board)
- to capture (an opposing piece)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- juego de tablero, juego de mesa, juego de sala
- tablero
- fichas, piezas, trebejos
- baraja, mazo de cartas
- tirar el dado
- mover hacia adelante, avanzar
- mover hacia atrás, retroceder
- saltar
- casilleros, casillas, escaques
- capturar, comer

Edit: Added Gonzalo's additions.

Comment: Otras opciones comunes (que quizá podrían ser incluidas en la respuesta): *juego de sala* (for "board game"), *baraja* (for "deck of cards"), *casillas* (for "squares"), *comer* (for "to capture"). By the way, welcome to Spanish.SE!

Comment: Thanks! Agregué tus traducciones. “Baraja” especialmente es mucho mejor, un mazo puede no tener todas las cartas.